# makefiles, função include

Tags: makefile

Eu estou tentando analisar o `makefile` abaixo. Mas eu fico sem entender como se encaixa a parte de baixo com o resto.

```
%.d: %.cpp
<TAB> g++ $< -MM -MT '$*.o $*.d ' -MD $(CPPFLAGS)
```

cria um arquivo `.d` que contem uma informação de tipo

```
   Fraction.o: Fraction.cpp Fraction.h
```

ou seja o arquivo a compilar com suas dependências.

Vem depois o

```
-include $(CPPSOURCES:.cpp=.d)
```

que vai incluir a linha anterior no `makefile`

Beleza, isso vai mostrar as dependências de todos os arquivos cpp a compilar. Mas nenhum comando é associado.

O comando de compilar vem com o target:

```
 %.o: %.cpp
 <TAB> g++ -c $< $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@
```

Como esse target se associa com o `include`?

Aqui o código completo:

```
CPPUNIT_PATH=/diretorio_onde_esta_o_cppunit
INCLUDE_DIR=$CPPUNIT_PATH)/include
LIB_DIR=$(CPPUNIT_PATH)/lib
LIBS=-lcppunit

CPPFLAGS=-I$(INCLUDE_DIR)
LDFLAGS=-L$(LIB_DIR) $(LIBS)

CPPSOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)

all: ftest

ftest: $(CPPSOURCES:.cpp=.o)
<TAB> g++ -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
<TAB> g++ -c $< $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@

clean
<TAB> -rm -f *.o ftest *~

remade:
<TAB> $(MAKE) clean
<TAB> $(MAKE)

-include $(CPPSOURCES:.cpp=.d)

 %.d: %.cpp
 <TAB> g++ $< -MM -MT '$*.o $*.d ' -MD $(CPPFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

1. `makefile` faz a expansão de suas variáveis e comandos trabalhando com substituição de texto;
2. arquivos incluídos podem ser gerados novamente e, nesse caso, a leitura do `makefile` é reiniciada;
3. um alvo pode ter múltiplas dependências, inclusive dependências escritas em momentos distintos;
4. `makefile` é mágico, as vezes até demais, e isso é confuso ;-)

Um exemplo do item 3, que indica que `Fraction.o` depende ao mesmo tempo de `Fraction.cpp` e `Fraction.h`:

```
Fraction.o: Fraction.cpp
<TAB> g++ -c $< $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@

Fraction.o: Fraction.cpp Fraction.h
```

---

Primeiramente, gostaria de falar que conhecia o `include file` do `makefile`, mas esse `-include file` me intrigou.

O `include` sem o traço na frente força o `makefile` a inserir, ipsis litteris, o conteúdo do arquivo dentro do `makefile` atual. Obviamente que isso gera encrenca caso o arquivo não exista (e não seja possível criá-lo), então o `make` explode de maneira catastrófica.

Já o `-include` funciona de modo quase igual ao `include`, a única diferença está na ausência do arquivo incluído (e na incapacidade de gerá-lo novamente também). Nesse caso, o `-include` passa silenciosamente sem alertar erros. Mais detalhes pode ser encontrada na [documentação do *Include* do *GNU Makefile*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html).

Aí vamos para o mistério dos arquivos `.d`. Segundo nota na [documentação do *GNU Makefile*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html#Automatic-Prerequisites), arquivos `.d` são arquivos `makefile` normais. Nesse caso e em casos mais mundanos, o arquivo `.d` é um `makefile` gerado dinamicamente que é atualizado sob demanda, contendo regras de dependência implícitas. Note que você colocou o jeito como ele cria esse arquivos em seu próprio exemplo:

```
%.d: %.cpp
<TAB> g++ $< -MM -MT '$*.o $*.d ' -MD $(CPPFLAGS)
```

Aqui, você está dizendo que qualquer arquivo que termine em `.d` pode ser gerado a partir de um arquivo de mesmo prefixo porém extensão `.cpp`.

Agora vem a mágica. Você precisa compilar para um arquivo objeto `.o` uma fonte qualquer `.cpp`. Eu particularmente não lembro como o `makefile` lida com múltiplas regras de criação, mas eu me lembro como ele lida com dependências.

Vou focar aqui apenas nos arquivo `Fraction`, ignorando os outros por hora.

No começo, `makefile` irá ler seu arquivo e expandir todas as variáveis e comandos que ele encontrar (e que for possível). Eu vou ignorar algumas variáveis que são específicas suas, como `$(INCLUDE_DIR)`, `$(LIBS)` e tantas outras. Então, a primeira expansão que ele irá se preocupar é `CPPSOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)`. Como estamos agora focando só no `Fraction`, isso irá expandir para `CPPSOURCES = Fraction.cpp`. Até então, não há nenhuma linha de dependência no seu `makefile`, apenas variáveis.

Logo em seguida, ele encontra a primeira regra: `all: ftest`. Então, efetivamente, o seu `makefile` nesse momento tem o seguinte conteúdo:

```
all: ftest
```

Um alvo `.PHONY`, que não será gerado um arquivo com seu nome, mas tem um identificador para ajudar na hora de realizar o build.

A próxima linha com conteúdo é `ftest: $(CPPSOURCES:.cpp=.o)`. Note que a variável `CPPSOURCES` está sofrendo uma expansão em que a string `.cpp` é trocada pela string `.o`. Como seu conteúdo nesse momento é `Fraction.cpp`, essa expansão retorna `Fraction.o`. O estado atual do `makefile` é:

```
all: ftest
ftest: Fraction.o
<TAB> g++ -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

A variável especial automática `$@` expande para o alvo, portanto na hora de rodar o comando ela se chamará `ftest`; já a variável especial automática `$^` expande para todas as dependências diretas de `ftest`, que no nosso caso é `Fraction.o`; note que, ao ter mais de um arquivo `.cpp`, a variável `CPPSOURCES` irá expandir para ter mútiplas valores `.o` na dependência de `ftest`. Como elas são variáveis especiais que dependem somente do `target` e das `dependencies`, irei deixar aqui. Mais sobre variáveis automáticas na [documentação do *GNU Makefile*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables)

Logo em seguida, encontra-se a regra `%.o: %.cpp`, que transforma um arquivo `.cpp` em um arquivo `.o`.

```
%.o: %.cpp
<TAB> g++ -c $< $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@
```

Aqui há o uso da variável especial automática `$<`. Diferente da `$^`, somente a primeira dependência é usada. Portanto, não importa quais outras dependências haja para gerar o arquivo `.o`, só será substituído em `$<` o nome do arquivo `.cpp`. Assim, temos que seu arquivo agora contém 3 dependências, com duas regras de criação:

```
all: ftest
ftest: Fraction.o
<TAB> g++ -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
<TAB> g++ -c $< $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@
```

Em seguida, entram mais dois alvos `.PHONY` antes de chegar no `-include`:

```
all: ftest
ftest: Fraction.o
<TAB> g++ -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
<TAB> g++ -c $< $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@

clean:
<TAB> -rm -f *.o ftest *~

remade:
<TAB> $(MAKE) clean
<TAB> $(MAKE)
```

Aqui, então, o `makefile` entra na linha da inclusão dos outros arquivos de `makefile`. Os arquivos são dados pela expansão `$(CPPSOURCES:.cpp=.d)`. No nosso caso, essa expansão gera `Fraction.d`. Então, temos que o `makefile` irá interpretar o seguinte comando: `-include Fraction.d`. Aqui as coisas ficam interessantes.

Neste caso, existem 5 alternativas possíveis:

1. o arquivo não existe, mas existe uma regra de criação para ele;
2. o arquivo não existe, nem tampouco há regra de criação para ele;
3. o arquivo existe, mas há uma regra para ele indicando que ele está desatualizado;
4. o arquivo existe, e ele está atualizado de acordo com a regra;
5. o arquivo existe, porém não há regra para ele.

Até o momento, não é possível distinguir se o arquivo está nas alternativas `1,2` ou se está nas `2,3,4`, pois não chegamos no final do arquivo e não encontramos regras de criação para ele. Vamos supor no momento que o arquivo exista, e que foi feita alguma alteração em `Fraction.cpp`. Nesse ponto, com essa suposição, o conteúdo do `makefile`é o seguinte:

```
all: ftest
ftest: Fraction.o
<TAB> g++ -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
<TAB> g++ -c $< $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@

clean:
<TAB> -rm -f *.o ftest *~

remade:
<TAB> $(MAKE) clean
<TAB> $(MAKE)

Fraction.o: Fraction.cpp Fraction.h
```

Logo em seguida, ele encontra uma regra para atualizar os arquivos `.d`, `%.d: %.cpp`. Como estamos na suposição de que o arquivo `.cpp` está mais atualizado do que o `.d`. Neste caso, os seguintes passos vão acontecer:

1. é usada a regra de geração para `Fraction.d`, pois ele é um arquivo incluído e, portanto, dependência deste `makefile` atual;
2. o `makefile` é lido novamente, do zero, desde o começo.

Se o arquivo `Fraction.d` não existisse a priori, ele também seguiria os mesmos passos de criar o arquivo e ler novamente o `makefile`. Mais você encontra na [documentação do *GNU Makefile*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html#Remaking-Makefiles).

Após o arquivo ser regerado, ele seguirá todos os passos de leitura e expansões do `makefile` novamente, até que finalmente ele termina no seguinte formato:

```
all: ftest
ftest: Fraction.o
<TAB> g++ -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
<TAB> g++ -c $< $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@

clean:
<TAB> -rm -f *.o ftest *~

remade:
<TAB> $(MAKE) clean
<TAB> $(MAKE)

Fraction.o: Fraction.cpp Fraction.h
%.d: %.cpp
<TAB> g++ $< -MM -MT '$*.o $*.d ' -MD $(CPPFLAGS)
```

Aqui, o arquivo `Fraction.d` está mais atualizado do que `Fraction.cpp`, pois acabou de ser gerado, portanto ele não precisará se preocupar novamente com a criação do `Fraction.d`. A partir daqui, o `makefile` irá executar as  construções; até então ele só estava se preparando.

Estou assumindo que você não passou nenhum parâmetro e que não exista nenhum arquivo chamado `all` no seu diretório de trabalho (para evitar que um arquivo chamado `all` impeça sua compilação, leia sobre [alvos`.PHONY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html#Phony-Targets)). `all` depende de `ftest` e de nada mais.

Para executar `ftest`, você precisa de `Fraction.o`.

Existe uma regra de criação implícita para `Fraction.o` e, além disso, também há uma outra dependência declarada para ele. Ao todo, o conjunto dependências de `Fraction.o` é a união das dependências declaradas; no caso, temos `Fraction.o: Fraction.cpp Fraction.h` e `%.o: %.cpp` (que expande em `Fraction.o: Fraction.cpp`), daí a união é `Fraction.o: Fraction.cpp Fraction.h` (não se aceita repetições na união). Portanto, dado que o arquivo `Fraction.cpp` ou o `Fraction.h` seja atualizado, o arquivo `Fraction.o` precisa ser gerado.

Não há regras de criação nem para `Fraction.cpp` nem para `Fraction.h`, portanto o arquivo `Fraction.o` já está pronto para ser gerado com o comando `g++ -c Fraction.cpp $(CPPFLAGS) -o Fraction.o`.

Tendo todas as suas dependências geradas, `ftest` está pronto para ser gerado com o comando `g++ -o ftest Fraction.o $(LDFLAGS)`.

Após `ftest` ser gerado, não há mais dependência para `all`, portanto o alvo foi gerado com sucesso.