# Erro ao criar arquivo Makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

Quando estou tentando usar o arquivo Makefile com o seguinte conteudo:

```
all: teste
teste: arp_discover.o arp_poisoning.o 
        gcc -o teste arp_discover.o arp_poisoning.o
arp_discover.o: arp_discover.c arp_discover.h
        gcc -o arp_discover.o -c arp_discover.c -W -lpthread -Wall
arp_poisoning.o: arp_poisoning.c 
        gcc -o arp_poisoning.o -c arp_poisoning.c -W -lpthread -Wall
clean:
        rm -rf *.o
mrproper: clean
        rm -rf teste
```

O seguinte erro é apresentado:

```
gcc -o teste arp_discover.o arp_poisoning.o
arp_poisoning.o:(.data+0x0): múltipla definição de `capacidade'
arp_discover.o:(.data+0x0): definido primeiramente aqui
arp_poisoning.o:(.bss+0x0): múltipla definição de `posicao'
arp_discover.o:(.bss+0x0): definido primeiramente aqui
arp_poisoning.o: na função `sendRequests':
arp_poisoning.c:(.text+0x0): múltipla definição de `sendRequests'
arp_discover.o:arp_discover.c:(.text+0x0): definido primeiramente aqui
arp_poisoning.o: na função `receiveReplies':
arp_poisoning.c:(.text+0x2e2): múltipla definição de `receiveReplies'
arp_discover.o:arp_discover.c:(.text+0x2e2): definido primeiramente aqui
arp_poisoning.o: na função `getHosts':
arp_poisoning.c:(.text+0x553): múltipla definição de `getHosts'
arp_discover.o:arp_discover.c:(.text+0x553): definido primeiramente aqui
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'teste' failed
make: *** [teste] Error 1
```

Sendo que no arquivo arp_poisoning existe a seguinte dependência:

```
/* utilizando os utilitarios */
#include "arp_discover.c"
```

Comment: o makefile parece correto. Pode mostrar os arquivos que você está compilando?

Comment: Opa, bem eles são gigantes hehehe, mas basicamente o que existe é uma arquivo .h que define o arp_discover e essa dependência declarada dentro do arquivo arp_poisoning com o #include "arp_discover.c"

Comment: pelo makefile dava para saber disso. Pelos erros apresentados, você está declarando `capacidade`, `posicao`, `sendRequests`, `receiveReplies` e `getHosts` mais de uma vez.

Comment: pois é, mas não deveria, pois o meu código está declarando isso somente em um arquivo, você vai conseguir dar uma olhada no código seguindo o link do github: https://github.com/emanoelvianna/trabalho-redes, o código do makefile está diferente e a dependência no arp_poisoning está comentada, o resto é o mesmo que estou usando.

Comment: @Emanoel, não inclua arquivos `.c`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **Repita comigo**: jamais incluirei `.c` sem maiores razões

Podemos usar de modo mais eficiente o seu `Makefile` usando variáveis automáticas. Veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193043/64969) explicando um pouco sobre a variável `$<`. Para uma explicação extensa e mais voltada para compilação de arquivos C/C++, [veja essa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/197892/64969).

Sobre o uso dos arquivos `.h`, eu discorro um pouco sobre *forward declaration* [nessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210063/64969).

Agora, vamos ao foco. O arquivo `arp_poisoning.c` não depende do `arp_discover.c`, mas depende das declarações dele. Depende das *forward declarations* dele, que ficam contidas no `.h`. Para explicar o que está realmente ocorrendo, preciso agora entrar em detalhes de como funciona a compilação de um arquivo fonte em C.

## Compilação de arquivo C

Por incrível que pareça, o compilador C trabalha apenas uma única entrada de cada vez. Ele pega essa entrada do chamado pré processador C. Na próxima seção vou falar o que é o pré processador.

C é uma linguagem que na prática é *parseada* em uma única passada, como boa parte das linguagens de programação. O compilador vai identificar toda definição + referências abertas e vai colocar seus resultados nos chamados arquivos objetos (arquivos `.o` no mundo do GCC).

O que seria considerado definição nesse caso? Uma função com corpo está definitivamente definida. Uma variável global também está definida.

E referência aberta? Isso é um conceito para coisas que deveriam existir mas não existem no contexto do código compilado. Talvez exista por fora, mas o compilador não é capaz de fechar qual a implementação que está sendo de fato usada.

Quando acontece uma referência aberta? Acontece quando você informa que a variável existe, porém o arquivo não é "dono" dela; a variável é **externa** (`extern`). Isso acontece com a variável [`errno`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/errorno_h.htm). Outro ponto de referência aberta? Funções que tiveram *forward declaration*.

Você pode e deve criar arquivos objetos com referências abertas. Porém você só pode criar executável depois de fechar todas as referências estáticas, depois de fazer todas as ligações, todos os *binds*. E quem faz isso? O linkador.

## O linkador

O papel do linkador é resolver todas as referências abertas em cima do conjunto de arquivos objetos e bibliotecas disponíveis.

Como ele faz isso? Com um protocolo. Uma função em C vai ter um nome, e esse nome é reconhecido pelo linkador e gerado pelo compilador. O GCC gera esse valor colocando `_` na frente do nome C da função. Por exemplo, a função `capacidade` teria seu nome de linkagem `_capacidade`.

O linkador vai procurar toda referência aberta e, caso não tenha encontrada a função para fechar essa referência, ele vai manter apontada essa referência aberta. Caso encontre uma definição de função, ele adicionará ao conjunto de funções conhecidas; caso essa função tenha uma referência aberta para ela, o linkador vai fechar a referência. Caso seja encontrada uma segunda definição, o linkador aborta com erro: duplicidade de definição.

## O pré processador C

O pré processador C é um processador de textos em geral; também é conhecido como CPP. Ele surgiu para trabalhar com arquivos C, mas podem ser usados para processar outros arquivos textuais.

De modo geral, tudo que contém `#` em linha de código C vai ser interpretado pelo CPP. Depois de um `#`, vai vir um comando CPP. O CPP também fará substituição textual de tudo aquilo que está definido para pré processamento.

Alguns comandos:

- `#define MACRO val`: define `MACRO` com o valor `val`; isso significa que toda string no texto, a partir do momento da definição de `MACRO` será substituída *verbatim* por `val`; caso o valor não seja definido, assume-se string vazia; pode-se usar argumentos para a definição;
- `#include "abcde"`: considera que,  o exato ponto deste `include` ele deve levar em consideração como continuação da entrada todo conteúdo do arquivo `abcde`, pré processando `abcde` também; todas as definições prévias continuam valendo.

### O que acontece ao incluir outro `.c` na minha fonte?

Vamos lá. Tomemos como exemplo um arquivo mais simples. Vou chamar de `hello.c` e o `say_hello.c`.

`hello.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void hello() {
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

`say_hello.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.c"

int main() {
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Vamos ver qual vai ser a saída do CPP, que é a entrada do compilador propriamente dito? Vou ignorar a parte da biblioteca padrão porque não vem ao caso:

```
/* coisas do stdio.h */
void hello() {
    printf("hello\n");
}

int main() {
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Ok. Então, ao compilar `say_hello.c`, teremos duas definições devidamente implementadas e uma referência aberta no `say_hello.o`. As definições são:

1. `_hello`
2. `_main`

A referência aberta é:

1. `printf`

Ao mandar o GCC juntar o `say_hello.o` com o `hello.o`, teremos duas definições para `_hello`. O que significa que não vai rolar a compilação.

## Como proceder?

Simples: inclua os *headers*/`.h`. Compile os arquivos `.c`individualmente. Junte tudo em um grande executável. A resposta com a compilação em C++ trata disso muito bem. De modo geral, pode ser feito isso também no `makefile`:

```
.PHONY: all

all : teste

teste : arp_discover.o arp_poisoning.o
    gcc -o $@ $^

%.o : %.c
     gcc -o $@ $< -c

arp_discover.o : arp_discover.h

arp_poisoning.o : arp_discover.h
```

Comment: muito legal sua explicação, obrigado.