# É possível usar for loop para reduzir código em C?

Tags: c, loop, for

Tenho a seguinte função:**A**.
É possível usar o for loop **B** para gerar as declarações como na função **A**?
O que usar ao invés de **printf** para que se torne uma declaração?

```
printf("%s%i%s\n",ad1,i,ad2);
```

**A**

```
void functionX(unsigned int buf) {
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A15));
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A14));
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A13));
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A12));
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A11));
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A10));
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A9 ));
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A8 ));
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A7 ));
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A6 ));
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A5 ));
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A4 ));
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A3 ));
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A2 ));
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A1 ));
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A0 ));    
}
```

**B**

```
void functionX(unsigned int buf) {
    int i;
    char ad1[]="H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A";
    char ad2[]="));";

    for (i=15; i>=0; i--) {
      printf("%s%i%s\n",ad1,i,ad2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Que tal algo assim:

```
void functionX( unsigned int buf )
{
    int i;

    int addr[16] = { EEPROM_A15, EEPROM_A14, EEPROM_A13, EEPROM_A12,
                   EEPROM_A11, EEPROM_A10, EEPROM_A9, EEPROM_A8,
                   EEPROM_A7, EEPROM_A6, EEPROM_A5, EEPROM_A4,
                   EEPROM_A3, EEPROM_A2, EEPROM_A1, EEPROM_A0 };

    for( i = 0; i < 16; i++ ) {
        H8_3687_pulse( EEPROM_MASK( buf, addr[i] ) );
    }

}
```

Comment: Lacobus, no ponto! Vou escolher a sua resposta! Como se chama esta solução com array? Biblioteca, Lista?

Answer (score 6):

Você tem um caso muito especial aí. Creio que `EEPROM_A##` seja uma família de macros. Macros funcionam a nível de pré processamento do arquivo fonte, um processamento puramente textual que ocorre antes de chamar o compilador C propriamente dito. Entro em mais detalhes sobre o pré processador [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213804/64969).

Nesse caso, não há muito a ser feito. Em algum momento você precisa acessar cada uma dessas macros... O que pode ser feito é acessar a essas macros em um momento anterior, povoando um vetor com esses valores.

Caso não sejam macros, caso sejam variáveis, a linguagem também não fornece facilidade alguma em relação a isso. C é uma linguagem compilada, e o nome das variáveis serve apenas como mnemônico para que o programador (e o compilador também) possa apelidar uma região de memória. Após a compilação, o nome deixa de existir e passa a existir apenas a região de memória, então não há muito a que se fazer em relação a isso.

No caso das variáveis, se elas foram compiladas alinhadas como se fossem um vetor, é possível usar um pouco de ponteiros para fazer essa operação em um laço. Recapitulando: se as variáveis foram **compiladas alinhadas como se fossem um vetor**, algo que depende da compilação da biblioteca de onde você pega esses valores. Se você está compilando a biblioteca ou se isso não está explicitamente escrito na documentação dela, então podemos assumir que o método a seguir não é confiável.

```
int i;
int *eeprom_a0_pt;

eeprom_a0_pt = &EEPROM_A0;

for (i = 15; i >= 0; i--) {
    H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, *(eeprom_a0_pt + i) ));
}
```

Mas você só pode fazer isso se e somente se for garantido que as variáveis foram compiladas alinhadas como se fossem um vetor.

Eu procurei alguma alternativa usando a extensão GCC de macros variádicas, mas não consegui encontrar nada que pudesse fazer esse processamento.

---

> a seção abaixo foi escrita antes de eu tomar conhecimento do tcc, servindo então para o C tradicional sem bibliotecas externas; para maiores detalhes, veja a resposta do [Wtrmute](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214106/64969)

Mas por que disso tudo? Simples, pelo design da linguagem C.

Como expliquei mais acima, o nome das variáveis se perde na compilação. Se for macro, a substituição de texto ocorre antes da compilação.

Para fazer isso de pegar a saída do `printf` e executá-la de maneira correta, você precisaria avaliar (*evaluate* em inglês) a expressão. Fazer essa avaliação é o equivalente a chamar um compilador para aquele trecho de código, também conhecido como chamar a função `eval` disponível em algumas linguagens de programação.

A prática de geração dinâmica de código para ser avaliada em *run time* é algo típico de Lisp e Bash, sendo não muito comum em C.

Answer (score 3):

Embora ordinariamente eu siga a resposta do Lacobus, este é um bom lugar para lembrar que o compilador [tcc](https://bellard.org/tcc/) tem uma biblioteca de vínculo dinâmico que permite a compilação de código dinâmico:

```
#include "libtcc.h"

void (*)(unsigned int)
compilar_funcao(TCCState * s) {
    char buffer[1024];
    char * ptr = buffer;

    /* monta o texto do programa */
    ptr += sprintf(ptr,
        "#include \"header.h\"\n" // cabeçalho com as definições de EEPROM_MASK e EEPROM_A*
        "void f(unsigned int buf) {\n"
    );
    for (int i = 15; i >= 0; i --) {
        ptr += sprintf(ptr,
            "H8_3687_pulse(EEPROM_MASK(buf, EEPROM_A%d));\n",
            i
        );
    }
    ptr += sprintf(ptr, "}");
    /* fornecer os caminhos para inclusão de cabeçalhos */
    tcc_add_include_path(s, "./"); /* aqui o diretório atual */
    /* compilar para a memória */
    tcc_set_output_type(s, TCC_OUTPUT_MEMORY);
    if (tcc_compile_string(buffer) == 1)
        return NULL;
    /* resolver as referências a símbolos externos */
    tcc_add_symbol(s, "H8_3687_pulse", H8_3687_pulse);
    /* fazer a relocação (trabalho do linker) */
    if (tcc_relocate(s, TCC_RELOCATE_AUTO) < 0)
        return NULL;
    /* retornar o símbolo global compilado (neste caso, chamado f */
    return tcc_get_symbol(s, "f");
}
```

Na inicialização/finalização do programa tem que criar o `TCCState*` para passar para a função `compilar_funcao()` acima:

```
int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    TCCState * s = tcc_new();
    /* resto do programa... */
    tcc_delete(s);
    return 0;
}
```

É claro, neste caso específico é um *overkill* tremendo, mas é uma boa opção caso a geração de código dinâmico não consiga ser evitada...

Comment: Não conhecia essa opção, muito legal. No caso, o `tcc` vai precisar ter acesso ao `header.h` em runtime, né? Basta colocar o arquivo do lado do executável?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado: Na verdade, tem uma chamada para estabelecer o _include path_ ou o _system include path_ que ele vai usar para procurar os cabeçalhos. Vou adicionar na resposta. Suspeito que, no Windows, ele sempre procure no diretório atual, mas não custa ser explícito.

Comment: Muito agradecido Wtrmute e JeffersonQuesato, muito bom. Eu esqueci de acrescentar que como estou endereçando um microcontrolador Renesas H8/3687; obrigatoriamente devo utilizar um compilador da Hitachi. Não sei ainda se é possível usar #include "libtcc.h". Vamos fazer contato com o suporte da Renesas hoje e chegar isso. Grande abraco. Vou escolher a resposta do Lacobus.