# Erro ao tentar compilar arquivos .h em c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

O código é este:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "classeID.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    id label("default", 0);
    cout << "Nome: " << label.getName() << "\n";
    cout << "Idade: " << label.getIdade() << "\n";
    return 0;
}

//arquivo .h----------

#ifndef classeID_H
#define classeID_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class id {
private:
    string name;
    int idade;
public:
    id(string n, int i);
    ~id(void);
    string getName();
    int getIdade();
private:
    void welcome();
};
#endif // !classeID_H

//arquivo de implementação da classe id(classeID.cpp)----------

#include "classeID.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

id::id(string n, int i) {
    welcome();
    this->name = n;
    this->idade = i;
}

id::~id(void) {
    cout << "Objeto label destruido.\n";
    system("pause > null");
}

void id::welcome(void) {
    cout << "Bem vindo\n";
}
string id::getName() {
    return name;
}

int id::getIdade() {
    return idade;
}
```

Uso o Visual Studio como IDE. O erro que ele me retorna é LNK2019. Já busquei por esse erro e não compreendi nada. Minha duvida também está em como o arquivo .h se associa ao arquivo classeID.cpp. Enfim só sei que nada sei rsrs...

Comment: Assim, o termo usado não é compilar `.h`, ele é apenas incluído no fonte que o importa _verbatim_. Vou procurar aqui uma resposta que fala um pouco do processo de compilação em C/C++

Comment: Leia um pouco mais de como funciona o processador C é como o CPP atua [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213804/64969)

Comment: Funciona bem no Codeblocks, é mesmo configuração do Linker no Visual Studio

Comment: Essa outra resposta pode te encaminhar melhor: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19886397

Comment: @Isac eu creio que o `classID.cpp` não está sendo compilado

Comment: É capaz sim, ele tem que confirmar que a solução está a compilar e linkar todos os ficheiros

Comment: After_, quais os arquivos objetos gerados? Arquivo objeto tem extensão `.obj` no Visual Studio (já no gcc são os `.o`)

Comment: Posta o código inteiro, incluindo linha e tudo, de preferencia copia o log todo, só assim vamos poder saber o que esta faltando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o problema observando o conteúdo da pagina https://stackoverflow.com/q/19886397 indicada por @Jefferson Quesado. Os arquivos classeID.h e classeID.cpp nunca estiveram devidamente associados ao arquivo principal POO.cpp. Recriei os arquivos dentro das mesma solução e o programa compilou normalmente. Resolvido.