# Melhorar a interação entre arquivos

Tags: c++, packages

Estou criando uma linguagem de programação em C++, e pretendo fazer algum sistema para trabalhar com vários arquivos.

No processo de compilação simples, o interpretador cria arquivos `.cpp` e `.h` e depois compila todos juntos em um executável, e em seguida apaga os arquivos. Eu pretendo adicionar um sistema que compile os arquivos para `.o`, e depois apaga os arquivos `.cpp` e `.h`. O problema é que o `#include` do C++ apenas copia o conteúdo do `.h`, assim , se eu modificar um arquivo e for compilá-lo em `.o`, terei que compilar também todos que dependem dele. Também, com esse sistema não posso importar também uma única função ou classe, como é feito no Python usando `from ... import` por exemplo.

Minha pergunta é, isso que eu disse é totalmente certo, e se sim, é possível driblar isso? Lembrando que eu não quero que o programador veja os arquivos `.cpp` e `.h`, a não ser caso isso for pedido.

Comment: Você então compila para C++ e depois gera o arquivo objeto? Eu respondi algo sobre como funciona a compilação de um arquivo C/C++, com notas sobre inclusão e tal. Vou te mandar, pode te ajudar

Comment: Pode interessar: como funciona a questão do `#include<arquivo.h>`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213804/64969