# Como enviar diretiva do programação do programa principal para alguma biblioteca?

Tags: c, c++, diretivas-de-compilação

Possuo uma biblioteca que gera um resultado de dois permitidos. Isto se dá pela definição, dentro da própria biblioteca, das diretiva `#define __SE8R01__` ou `#define __RF24L01P__`.

O caso é que esta escolha deveria ser feita dentro do programa principal. No entanto não estou conseguindo alternativa para isto, ficando a obrigatoriedade de se "mexer" no estado original da biblioteca.

A pergunta é como enviar alguma diretiva do programa principal, `main()`, para qualquer biblioteca em uso. Ou alguma alternativa, de forma que a biblioteca ao ser compilada reconheça a diretiva adequada?

Comment: As diretivas de pré-processamento só estão disponíveis a nível de compilação. Se você não tem controle sobre a compilação da biblioteca, não será possível fazer o que você deseja com um simples `#define`. Eu falo um pouco mais de detalhes do processo de compilação em C [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213804/64969)

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Diretivas de compilação indicam para o compilador como ele deve se comportar de diversas situações, portanto a única forma de mudar o seu valor é no momento da compilação da biblioteca usada, se não possui os fontes ou não pode compilá-la então nada pode ser feito para mudar o comportamento da biblioteca em questão.