# ERRO: static declaration of follows non-static declaration

Tags: c

Meu código está com o seguinte erro e não estou enxergando e nem entendendo do que se trata.

> 80:6: error: static declaration of 'print_menu' follows non-static
>   declaration  void print_menu(){
>
> 14:6: note: previous declaration of 'print_menu' was here  void
>   print_menu();

Código:

```
/* <-- BIBLIOTECAS --> */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "game_pvp.h"
/* <-- BIBLIOTECAS --> */

/* <-- DEFINES --> */
#define TAM 3
/* <-- DEFINES --> */

/* <-- DECLARAÇÃO DE PROCEDIMENTOS --> */
void print_menu();
void print_new_game();
void print_game_level();
void print_pvp_menu();
/* <-- DECLARAÇÃO DE PROCEDIMENTOS --> */

/* <-- MAIN --> */
int main(){
    char menu_choice;
    char game_shape[TAM][TAM];
    int start_player;

    srand(time(NULL));

    print_menu();
    menu_choice = getch();
    while(menu_choice < 49 || menu_choice > 51) {
        printf("\n Please enter a valid option");
        menu_choice = getch();
    }
    if(menu_choice == 49){
        system("cls");
        print_new_game();
        menu_choice = getch();
        while(menu_choice < 49 || menu_choice > 50) {
            printf("\n Please enter a valid option");
            menu_choice = getch();
        }
        if(menu_choice == 49){
            system("cls");
            print_game_level();
            menu_choice = getch();
            while(menu_choice < 49 || menu_choice > 51) {
                printf("\n Please enter a valid option ");
                menu_choice = getch();
            }
            system("cls");
            // CHAMA JOGADOR vs IA Passando o nivel
        }
        else{
            system("cls");
            print_pvp_menu();
            start_player = (rand() % 2) + 1;
            if(start_player == 1){
                printf("\n  O Player 1 comeca (press any key)");
            }
            else{
                printf("\n  O Player 2 comeca (press any key)");
            }
            getch();
            system("cls");
            // CHAMA JOGADOR vs JOGADOR Passando a vez

            game_pvp(game_shape, start_player);
        }

    }
    // Aqui entra game save e EXIT


    system("pause");
}

/* <-- MAIN --> */

/* <-- PROCEDIMENTOS --> */
void print_menu(){
    printf("\n -=- JOGO DA VELHA -=- \n");
    printf("\n 1 - New Game");
    printf("\n 2 - Saved game");
    printf("\n 3 - EXIT");
    printf("\n Enter your choice ");
}

void print_new_game(){
    printf("\n -=- JOGO DA VELHA -=- \n");
    printf("\n 1 - One player");
    printf("\n 2 - Two players");
    printf("\n Enter your choice ");
}

void print_game_level(){
    printf("\n -=- GAME LEVEL -=- \n");
    printf("\n 1 - Easy");
    printf("\n 2 - Medium");
    printf("\n 3 - Hard");
    printf("\n Enter your choice ");
}

void print_pvp_menu(){
    printf("\n -=- PLAYER vs PLAYER -=- \n");
    printf("\n X - Player 1");
    printf("\n O - Player 2");
    printf("\n\n Sorteando quem vai comecar ...");
}
/* <-- PROCEDIMENTOS --> */
```

compiling_error:

```
C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\jogo da velha\main.c:80:6: error: static declaration of 'print_menu' follows non-static declaration
 void print_menu(){
      ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\jogo da velha\main.c:14:6: note: previous declaration of 'print_menu' was here
 void print_menu();
      ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\jogo da velha\main.c:88:6: error: static declaration of 'print_new_game' follows non-static declaration
 void print_new_game(){
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\jogo da velha\main.c:15:6: note: previous declaration of 'print_new_game' was here
 void print_new_game();
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\jogo da velha\main.c:95:6: error: static declaration of 'print_game_level' follows non-static declaration
 void print_game_level(){
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\jogo da velha\main.c:16:6: note: previous declaration of 'print_game_level' was here
 void print_game_level();
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\jogo da velha\main.c:103:6: error: static declaration of 'print_pvp_menu' follows non-static declaration
 void print_pvp_menu(){
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\jogo da velha\main.c:17:6: note: previous declaration of 'print_pvp_menu' was here
 void print_pvp_menu();
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\jogo da velha\main.c:108:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
 }
 ^
```

---

game_pvp.h:

```
#include "game_pvp.c"
```

game_pvp.c:

```
int game_pvp(char game_shape[3][3], int turn){
    char x, y;

    if(turn == 1){
        print_shape(turn);
        printf("\n Enter a value for X: ");
        x = getch();
        printf("%c",x);
        while(x < 49 || x > 51 ){
            printf("\n Please enter a valid option");
            x = getch();
        }
        printf("\n Enter a value for Y: ");
        y = getch();
        printf("%c",y);
        while(y < 49 || y > 51 ){
            printf("\n Please enter a valid option");
            y = getch();
        }
    }
    else{
        print_shape(turn);
        printf("\n Enter a value for X: ");
        x = getch();
        printf("%c",x);
        while(x < 49 || x > 51 ){
            printf("\n Please enter a valid option");
            x = getch();
        }
        printf("\n Enter a value for Y: ");
        y = getch();
        printf("%c",y);
        while(y < 49 || y > 51 ){
            printf("\n Please enter a valid option");
            y = getch();
    }

}

void print_shape(int turn){

        printf("\n -=- PLAYER %i TURN -=- \n", turn);
        printf("\n");
        printf("      1   2   3   Y\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf(" 1    X | X | X \n");
        printf("     ---|---|--- \n ");
        printf("2    X | X | X \n");
        printf("     ---|---|--- \n ");
        printf("3    X | X | X \n");
        printf("\n X\n");

}
```

Comment: Tenta mudar para static void print_game()... na sua função

Comment: Deve ter um `print_menu()` em outro lugar. Alias um dos motivos que odeio declaração separado da definição.

Comment: Coloquei static na frente e não adiantou.

Comment: Tbm mudei o print_menu() para print_menu2() e continuou com o erro mas agora no print_menu2()

Comment: Qual o conteúdo do `.h`?

Comment: E qual o compilador? Se possível, quais flags de compilação?

Comment: Opa, Jefferson. Comentei a parte .h é voltou a funcionar, já vou colocar o conteúdo dele.

Comment: @GabrielDantas o problema está no `.h`, que você inclui o `.c`

Comment: Qual o problema do .h Jefferson ?

Comment: @GabrielDantas o `.h` não deve ter código, apenas declaração. Por isso, não inclua arquivos `.c`, o comportamento que o compilador vai executar não vai ser o que você espera, o ciclo de compilar um fonte C de modo separado é distinto daquele que você imagina; mais detalhes nessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213804/64969

Comment: Na resposta, eu boto o comportamento do `#include"hello.c"` em um projeto e mostrou qual a inconsistência gerada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema é que existe um descasamento de `{}` no arquivo `game_pvp.c`. Você esqueceu de fechar um `}` na função `int game_pvp(char game_shape[][3], int turn)`

Agora o grande problema mesmo é que vc está usando o arquivo .h de modo errado. Ele não tem a finalidade de incluir um arquivo .c, como vc fez, mas de ser um cabeçalho onde vc coloca as declarações das funções e estruturas que o seu programa irá usar.

Sendo assim, a forma correta de criar o `game_pvp.h`, seria algo do tipo:

```
#ifndef __GAME_PVP_H__
#define __GAME_PVP_H__

int game_pvp(char game_shape[][3], int turn);
void print_shape(int turn);

#endif /* __GAME_PVP_H__ */
```

Comment: Faz total sentido. Pensei que tinha sido erro de digitação do AP

Comment: Obrigado amigo, vou dar uma estudada sobre esse .h