# Como corrijo "referencia indefinida para 'função' em C?

Tags: c, c++, funções, compilação

Segue um exemplo simples de TAD, que apresenta o erro.

arquivo.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int teste();
```

arquivo.c

```
#include "arquivo.h"

int teste()
{
    int a=5, b=10;

    return a+b;
}
```

main.c

```
#include "arquivo.h"

int main()
{
    int r = teste();

    printf("\n\n%d\n\n",r);

    return 0;
}
```

e quando compilo aparece o erro abaixo.

[image: referencia indefinida para a 'função']

Comment: Mais sobre o assunto compilação: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213804/64969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inclua o `arquivo.c` na compilação, sem ele a função não é compilada e não existe, portanto não pode ser chamada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).